# Android Asynchronous Http Client "Invalid cookie header" Error

Tags: android, cookies, loopj

I am trying to use a HTTP POST request for the login, the server response is Ok but in the log there are multiple entries like this:

```
W/ResponseProcessCookies﹕ 
Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: _boss_session=2e3aef5b7a0ffc7946127f791223aea6e09dfbcc;
Version=1; 
Expires=Thu, 21-May-2015 14:42:47 GMT;
Max-Age=525600;
Path=/". Unable to parse expires attribute: Thu
```

My Client:

```
public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler){
    mClient.get(getAbsoluteURL(url), params, responseHandler);
}

public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler){
    mClient.post(getAbsoluteURL(url), params, responseHandler);
}

private static String getAbsoluteURL(String relativeUrl){
    return URL + relativeUrl;
}
```

And to use Client:

```
Client.post("tools/ident/login", new RequestParams(loginParams), responseHandler);
```

How can I solve this problem ?